# Keras + Tensorflow and Multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, python-multiprocessing

I'm using Keras with Tensorflow as backend.

I am trying to save a model in my main process and then load/run (i.e. call `model.predict`) within another process.

I'm currently just trying the naive approach from the docs to save/load the model: https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model.
So basically:

1. `model.save()` in main process
2. `model = load_model()` in child process
3. `model.predict()` in child process

However, it simply hangs on the `load_model` call.

Searching around I've discovered this potentially related answer suggesting that Keras can only be utilized in one process: [using multiprocessing with theano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176827/using-multiprocessing-with-theano) but am unsure if this is true (can't seem to find much on this).

Is there a way to accomplish my goal?  A high level description or short example is greatly appreciated.

Note: I've attempted approaches along the lines of passing a graph to the process but failed since it seems tensorflow graphs aren't pickable (related SO post for that here: [Tensorflow: Passing a session to a python multiprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900246/tensorflow-passing-a-session-to-a-python-multiprocess)).  If there is indeed a way to pass the tensorflow graph/model to the child process then I am open to that as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

From my experience - the problem lies in loading `Keras` to one process and then spawning a new process when the `keras` has been loaded to your main environment. But for some applications (like e.g. training a mixture of `Keras`models) it's simply better to have all of this things in one process. So what I advise is the following (a little bit cumbersome - but working for me) approach:

1. **DO NOT LOAD KERAS TO YOUR MAIN ENVIRONMENT**. If you want to load Keras / Theano / TensorFlow do it only in the function environment. E.g. **don't** do this:

   ```
   import keras

   def training_function(...):
       ...
   ```

   but do the following:

   ```
   def training_function(...):
       import keras
       ...
   ```
2. **Run work connected with each model in a separate process:** I'm usually creating workers which are making the job (like e.g. training, tuning, scoring) and I'm running them in separate processes. What is nice about it that whole memory used by this process is completely **freed** when your process is done. This helps you with loads of memory problems which you usually come across when you are using multiprocessing or even running multiple models in one process. So this looks e.g. like this:

   ```
   def _training_worker(train_params):
       import keras
       model = obtain_model(train_params)
       model.fit(train_params)
       send_message_to_main_process(...)

   def train_new_model(train_params):
       training_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=_training_worker, args = train_params)
       training_process.start()
       get_message_from_training_process(...)
       training_process.join()
   ```

Different approach is simply preparing different scripts for different model actions. But this may cause memory errors especially when your models are memory consuming. **NOTE** that due to this reason it's better to make your execution strictly sequential.

Comment: Marcin, thanks so much for you answer.  Side Question:  the SO question above stems from my desire to parallelize prediction for one model across multiple gpus.  I had asked an SO question about this a little while ago with no luck: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42409884/keras-tensorflow-prediction-on-multiple-gpus.   Would you mind taking a crack at it?  Thank you in advance.  Let me know if more detail is needed.

Comment: I'll have a look. This is something which I'm also interested in - but I haven't implemented such solution yet. I implemented a deamon like process which is receiving a image to process by a mixture of keras deep CNNs and this is where my example comes from.

Comment: Creating child process didn't helped me with this issue. When I interrupted keras model fitting I got a lot of hanging processes. During investigation I find out that multiprocessing pool wasn't wrapped with try-except and pool termination. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/data_utils.py#L548 I think it is the issue in keras but I'm not sure

Comment: `importlib.reload(keras)` inside the function, but it did not work

Answer (score 8):

I created one simple example to show how to run Keras model in multiple processes with multiple gpus. Hope this sample could help you.
https://github.com/yuanyuanli85/Keras-Multiple-Process-Prediction

Answer (score 1):

I created a decorator that fixed my code.

```
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Process

def child_process(func):
    """Makes the function run as a separate process."""
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        def worker(conn, func, args, kwargs):
            conn.send(func(*args, **kwargs))
            conn.close()
        parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(child_conn, func, args, kwargs))
        p.start()
        ret = parent_conn.recv()
        p.join()
        return ret
return wrapper

@child_process
def keras_stuff():
    """ Keras stuff here"""
```

Comment: There's a lot going on in this. The first thing is creating a decorator in python, this lets me make new functions with similar behaviors. For this decorator that behavior is running as a child process. Read more here if you haven't made a decorator before: https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/ Other than that the worker function simply executes the decorated function, `func` by using python multiprocessing. This code waits for the child process to complete before continuing. Go here to learn more about `multiprocessing`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html