# GridSearchCV hangs when called multiple types within script

Tags: python

I have been trying to use sklearn's GridSearchCV in the following script multiple types (once for every logistic regression, 3 times total). What ends up happening is that the first GridSearch for the first logistic regression is completed, and when the second gridsearch is about to begin, the terminal just hangs and nothing happens.

I am using Keras for logistic regression

I would love some feedback, as this problem is kind of annoying.

PS. This is my first time posting, so i am happy to provide additional information if needed.

Here's the script:

```
def braf():

    mut_pred=mutation_prediction(X_train_all_genes, Y_train_all_genes, X_valid=X_test_all_genes, Y_valid=Y_test_all_genes)

    print('Starting BRAF...')
    BRAF_history= History()
    braf_estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=mut_pred.braf_model, epochs=30, batch_size=15, verbose=0)
    braf_param_grid = dict(braf_learning_rate = 
    list(np.linspace(0,0.0001, num=5)), braf_lasso_rate = 
    list(np.linspace(0,0.0001, num=5)))
    braf_grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=braf_estimator, cv=2, 
    param_grid=braf_param_grid, n_jobs=30,pre_dispatch=5)
    braf_grid_result = braf_grid.fit(X_train_all_genes.values, Y_train_all_genes['BRAF_mutant'].values,callbacks=[BRAF_history])
    print('Done with BRAF')
    plot_loss(BRAF_history.history['loss'], title='BRAF LOSS')
    plot_accuracy(BRAF_history.history['acc'], title='BRAF Accuracy')

    BRAF_pred=list(map(lambda x:int(x),braf_grid.predict(X_test_all_genes.values)))

    return BRAF_pred
def kras():
    mut_pred=mutation_prediction(X_train_all_genes, Y_train_all_genes, X_valid=X_test_all_genes, Y_valid=Y_test_all_genes)
    print('Starting KRAS...')
    KRAS_history= History()
    kras_estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=mut_pred.kras_model, epochs=30, batch_size=15, verbose=0)
    kras_param_grid = dict(kras_learning_rate = 
    list(np.linspace(0,0.0001, num=10)), kras_lasso_rate = 
    list(np.linspace(0,0.0001, num=10)))
    kras_grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=kras_estimator, cv=2, param_grid=kras_param_grid, n_jobs=30,pre_dispatch=5)
    kras_grid_result = kras_grid.fit(X_train_all_genes.values, Y_train_all_genes['KRAS_mutant'].values,callbacks=[KRAS_history])
    print('Done with KRAS')
    plot_loss(KRAS_history.history['loss'], title='KRAS LOSS')
    plot_accuracy(KRAS_history.history['acc'], title='KRAS Accuracy')

    KRAS_pred=list(map(lambda x:int(x),kras_grid.predict(X_test_all_genes.values)))
    return KRAS_pred
def tp53():
    mut_pred=mutation_prediction(X_train_all_genes, Y_train_all_genes, X_valid=X_test_all_genes, Y_valid=Y_test_all_genes)
    print('Starting TP53...')
    TP53_history= History()
    tp53_estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=mut_pred.tp53_model, epochs=30, batch_size=15, verbose=0)
    tp53_param_grid = dict(tp53_learning_rate = 
    list(np.linspace(0,0.001, num=10)), tp53_lasso_rate = 
    list(np.linspace(0,0.0001, num=10)))
    tp53_grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=tp53_estimator, cv=2, param_grid=tp53_param_grid, jobs=30,pre_dispatch=5)
    tp53_grid_result = tp53_grid.fit(X_train_all_genes.values, Y_train_all_genes['TP53_mutant'].values,callbacks=[TP53_history])
    print('Done with TP53')
    plot_loss(TP53_history.history['loss'], title='TP53 LOSS')
    plot_accuracy(TP53_history.history['acc'], title='TP53 Accuracy')

    TP53_pred=list(map(lambda 
    x:int(x),tp53_grid.predict(X_test_all_genes.values)))
```

In my `main()` i call the above functions to do LR on these three genes and return the prediction with the best found combination of learning rate and lasso variable.

Any feedback would be helpful

**UPDATE**
When i interrupt the process i get the following:

```
Process ForkPoolWorker-58:
Process ForkPoolWorker-42:
Process ForkPoolWorker-56:
Process ForkPoolWorker-54:
Process ForkPoolWorker-52:
Process ForkPoolWorker-46:
Process ForkPoolWorker-40:
Process ForkPoolWorker-44:
Process ForkPoolWorker-38:
Process ForkPoolWorker-36:
Process ForkPoolWorker-60:
Process ForkPoolWorker-59:
Process ForkPoolWorker-43:
Process ForkPoolWorker-37:
Process ForkPoolWorker-39:
Process ForkPoolWorker-41:
Process ForkPoolWorker-45:
Process ForkPoolWorker-48:
Process ForkPoolWorker-53:
Process ForkPoolWorker-47:
Process ForkPoolWorker-57:
Process ForkPoolWorker-55:
Process ForkPoolWorker-49:
Process ForkPoolWorker-51:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FinalProjectV1.py", line 354, in <module>
    main()
  File "FinalProjectV1.py", line 332, in main
    KRAS_pred_test=kras()
  File "FinalProjectV1.py", line 309, in kras
    kras_grid_result = kras_grid.fit(X_train_all_genes.values,         Y_train_all_genes['KRAS_mutant'].values,callbacks=[KRAS_history])
  File "/soe/ianastop/lib/python3.6/site-        packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 639, in fit
    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
  File "/soe/ianastop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 789, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/soe/ianastop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 699, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "/soe/ianastop/venv/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 638, in get
    self.wait(timeout)
  File "/soe/ianastop/venv/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 635, in wait
    self._event.wait(timeout)
  File "/soe/ianastop/venv/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 551, in wait
    signaled = self._cond.wait(timeout)
  File "/soe/ianastop/venv/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 295, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

It looks like it has something to do with the multiprocess library?

Comment: This is, unfortunately, a fact. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the error on my MacBook Pro.

The issue here is with the tensorflow session. If a session is created in the parent process before `GridSearchCV.fit()`, it will hang for sure.

One possible solution would be to keep all session creation code restricted to the `KerasClassifer` class and the model creation function.

Additionally, you may want to restrict the memory usage of TF in either the model creation function or a subclass of `KerasClassifier`.

---

**Fast solution:**

```
n_jobs = 1
```

but it will take a long time to finish.

---

**References:**

[Session hang issue with python multiprocessing](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8220#issuecomment-370126516)

[Keras + Tensorflow and Multiprocessing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504669/keras-tensorflow-and-multiprocessing-in-python/42506478#42506478)

[Limit the resource usage for tensorflow backend](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1538)

[GridSearchCV Hangs On Second Run](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10538)

[scikit-lean GridSearchCV n_jobs != 1 freezing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44918220/5025009)

[keras + scikit-learn wrapper, appears to hang when GridSearchCV with n_jobs >1
Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47541477/5025009)

Comment: Thanks so much. Keeping all session code restricted to the KerasClassifier means to include `GridSearchCV.fit` in the` build_fn` variable right?

Comment: Yes exactly. However, there is no "stable" solution. Please consider upvoting my answer

Comment: I think i did. I just clicked that check.