# Running model.fit() and TensorBoard at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorboard, tf.keras

I have an interesting (for me) question about running model.fit() and tensorboard at the same time.

I did some research on internet about "Threading", "Processing", "Multi-processing", tried examples but couldn't solve my problem.

I want to run TensorBoard and model.fit() at the same time like:

```
from threading import Thread
import subprocess

def startTensorboard(log_dir):
    # Tried both
    os.system('tensorboard --logdir '+ log_dir)
    # subprocess.call(['tensorboard', '--logdir', log_dir])

tensorboard = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='logs', histogram_freq=0,
                          write_graph=True, write_images=False)

Thread(target = startTensorboard('logs')).start()

Thread(target = model.fit_generator(
                self.train_data_gen,
                steps_per_epoch=self.STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                validation_data = self.test_data_gen,
                validation_steps = self.VALID_STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                epochs=self.epoch,
                callbacks=[tensorboard])).start()
```

Is that possible? When I ran this code, TensorBoard is running but model.fit() isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a working example that I think does what you want. I'm using `Process` from the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module. Note that it seems to be important that the model is defined inside the function that you set as the `target` for `Process` when you're calling the `fit` function, as indicated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504669/keras-tensorflow-and-multiprocessing-in-python). I tried defining the model outside the function call and it would initialize the model, but then the training would just hang indefinitely.

When I run this on my laptop, tensorboard takes a little bit to get started, but usually by the time training hits epoch 70 tensorboard has launched and it continues to run until you kill it with Ctrl+C.

```
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from multiprocessing import Process


def startTensorboard(logdir):
    # Start tensorboard with system call
    os.system("tensorboard --logdir {}".format(logdir))


def fitModel():
    # Create your model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim=100))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    # Some mock training data
    data = np.random.random((1000, 100))
    labels = np.random.randint(2, size=(1000, 1))

    # Run the fit function
    model.fit(data, labels, epochs=100, batch_size=32)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run both processes simultaneously
    Process(target=startTensorboard, args=("logs",)).start()
    Process(target=fitModel).start()
```