# why keras model can't run in multiprocess pool in python?

Tags: python, keras, multiprocessing

I want to predict values by using the model
I use this code

```
from keras.models import load_model
import multiprocessing
model = load_model('CNN_MODEL.hdf')
def Net(x):
    print("test")
    return model.predict(x)

X_test=.....(a list )
pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=12)
Y=pool.map(Net,X_test)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

But it's too slow .
The out is

test
test
test
...
test
with 12 test
and then Stuck.
And my cpu is 36 core .
How to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keras + Tensorflow and Multiprocessing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504669/keras-tensorflow-and-multiprocessing-in-python)