# Does `model.predict(x,batch_size=n)` use multiple cores?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

When running `model.predict(features,batch_size=n)` with a `batch_size>1`, are those predictions made in parallel - aka across multiple cores at once?

> https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/eb7bf384017fd4eabdf500687bec552971cbd41c/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays_v1.py

I need to permute millions of columns, so I was hoping to infer many predictions simultaneously using `multiprocessing`. However, there are major challenges with this: [Keras + Tensorflow and Multiprocessing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504669/keras-tensorflow-and-multiprocessing-in-python)

One of my friends suggested stacking the data for use with batch_size as a workaround to increase performance, but I am wondering what the potential gains would be as it would be a big rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you parametrize the function call of [`tf.keras.model.predict()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict)

In the documentation you can find the parameters of predict, which has a `use_multiprocessing` parameter:

```
predict(
    x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None, callbacks=None, max_queue_size=10,
    workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False
)
```

Besides multiprocessing, predicting on batches instead of single samples benefits from vectorization, which additionally speeds up the prediction.

Comment: Important detail is that the `workers`/`use_multiprocessing` parameters could be used for `keras.utils.Sequence` inputs only.